# I'd like to limit the size of an element on desktop screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Adding `.col-xs-12` makes my element take up 100% space not only in mobile, how do I make it narrower on desktop? Should I nest additional column classes like `.col-md-4` and such?

[image]

This is what it looks like on desktop:

[image]

Comment: try giving your element classes for larger screen to avoid inherit classes and let me if that works

Comment: [Read The Fine Manual:](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) "Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths **greater than or equal to** the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any `.col-md-*` class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a `.col-lg-*` class is not present."

Answer (score 0):

.col-xs-12 will render as the default for all viewport sizes if you don't specify a different value for larger screens (eg .col-lg-4 / .col-md-6 / .col-sm-8)

Without seeing your code I can't tell what you are actually trying to achieve, but if you only want the bar to take up 50% in laptop/desktop views for example you would have the html as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
```

Keep in mind that you will need to balance out your grid in the larger views if you go this way (12 columns within the row) http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: It floats to the left when I use this. I'd like to know why it's not working in the first place

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the desired outcome? And it's 'not working' because col-xs-12 will render as full screen width across all viewport sizes unless you tell it to do otherwise - like I said already

Comment: I'd like to make it full-width on mobile. Using `width: 100%` in the 480 media query doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite following you but I think you're after the following behaviour

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

this will allow for full width on xs and sm viewports

Comment: In Bootstrap, xs corresponds to <768px, sm is ≥768px and <992px.  See the doc Grid Options table here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid